# Start Spring Boot War in a tomcat instance

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a functional Spring Boot Web App.

When i'm starting it from my Eclipse everything is fine (See @SpringBootApplication below)

But when I'm trying to load the generated WAR with tomcat 7, I'm getting the following errors in catalina log file

```
GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/schdtool-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.service.interfaces.ISettingService fr.myapp.schdtool.controller.AuthController.settingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.interfaces.ISettingDAO fr.myapp.schdtool.service.SettingService.settingDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.service.interfaces.ISettingService fr.myapp.schdtool.controller.AuthController.settingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.interfaces.ISettingDAO fr.myapp.schdtool.service.SettingService.settingDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.interfaces.ISettingDAO fr.myapp.schdtool.service.SettingService.settingDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.interfaces.ISettingDAO fr.myapp.schdtool.service.SettingService.settingDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settingDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager fr.myapp.schdtool.persistence.dao.AbstractDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 58 more
```

It seems that the webapp starts fine one time (saw in tomcat console), then restart and cannot complete the startup (???) but there's no trace of this first startup in catalina logs

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SchdtoolApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchdtoolApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("fr.myapp")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
            SimpleDriverDataSource d = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            d.setConnectionProperties(dProperties());
            d.setDriverClass(Driver.class);
            d.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb");
            d.setUsername("BNF0016779");
            d.setPassword("");
            return d;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("fr.myapp");

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
            return properties;        
    }

    private Properties dProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("spring.jpa.database", "POSTGRESQL");
        return properties;        
}   

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean configureScheduler() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean f = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        f.setDataSource(dataSource());
        f.setJobFactory(new SpringBeanJobFactory());
        f.setAutoStartup(false);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "3");
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "false");
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
        f.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        f.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        f.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
        return f;
    }
}
```

I also receive this error could it be involved ?

```
tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your problem is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
```

This problem comes when you have multiple entitymanager.

```
@Bean(name = "your-entity-manager-factory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring could'nt found @Configuration class

See the following solved question :

[Spring Boot App deployed in Tomcat : Quartz Scheduler bean is not visible from @Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227710/spring-boot-app-deployed-in-tomcat-quartz-scheduler-bean-is-not-visible-from/34229029#34229029)